# How to check Sign-Up with duplicate username in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using the following code to sign up in Parse account through Swift.

```
var user = PFUser()
user.username = self.userNameText.text
user.password = self.paswordText.text
user["mobileNumber"] = self.mobileNo as! String     //
user["authCode"] = self.authCode as! String
user["deviceId"] = deviceId
self.user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                let installation:PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
                installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        println("Installion Success")
                    } else {
                        println("Installation Error")
                    }
                })
                println("Singup Success")
            } else { 
                println(" error = \(error)")
            }
})
```

In this if the username entered is already saved in Parse, I want to give error, But now it is successfully signing up with 2 same usernames.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: If you use the default parse username it should not allow same usernames. This will only work in the case when you submit a second user with the same username while the other user is currently being registered in the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you want to Check that User is Already signup via Parse.com then You have to make a query in the User table If User already exists then don't allow him to again signup

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:textField.text];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
if (object != nil) {
    NSLog(@"User exist");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"User don`t exist");
}
}];
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Or, use a cloud code hook so you only have to make 1 API request in the success case instead of 2.

Comment: Instead of checking the user table in Parse, isnt there a simple way that Parse itself will return error on duplicate name?

Comment: unfortunately and amazingly, parse **do not yet handle checking of duplicates** ... this would have to be "the most obvious thing parse does not do, which they should do"

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"User")
        query.whereKey(key: "username", equalTo:self.userNameText.text)

query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if object != nil
    {
        //User exist
       //give appropriate message
    }
    else
    {
        //User don`t exist"
         //call signup method from here
        self.signUpNewUser()
    }
        }
```

New user signup

```
func signUpNewUser()
{
var user = PFUser()
user.username = self.userNameText.text
user.password = self.paswordText.text
user["mobileNumber"] = self.mobileNo as! String     //
user["authCode"] = self.authCode as! String
user["deviceId"] = deviceId
self.user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                let installation:PFInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
                installation["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                installation.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        println("Installion Success")
                    } else {
                        println("Installation Error")
                    }
                })
                println("Singup Success")
            } else { 
                println(" error = \(error)")
            }
})
}
```